# Should I use two domains, or a main domain / subdomain for my app?

Tags: seo, dns, email

I've purchases 2 domains for my site:

```
mysite.app
mysite.to
```

I first thought to put everything related to marketing and blogging in `mysite.to` and the app itself (SPA / no SEO needed) to `mysite.app`

Being far from a marketing / SEO expert I realized it may not be a good idea to have to handle two domains but I can't point out exactly the reasons. For example I figured to use `support@mysite.app` rather than `mysite.to` for emailing, but i've no idea if the ranking of `mysite.to` as a site will impact emails deliverability. In this case it would make my setup a bad choice, and I should change it.

I've to make a choice each time and I'm wondering the impact it'll have on the long run in term of everything related to marketing, traffic, etc.

Do people do that? Or do they stick to `app.mysite.to` as subdomain? Does it impact SEO at all?  Does it impact email deliverability or things like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question since no one looked at it. For multiple reasons it's better to have a unique `mysite.to` and a redirection  from `mysite.app` to `mysite.to` on top of it.

This will make everything related to code and redirection simpler, but also make it more straight forward for future customers to access the app; writing `mysite.app` isn't very practical for browser memories.

Comment: "since no one looked at it." it says it has 20 views :-) But the problem is that your question is subjective, so no definite answer in either case. 2 domains is good to separate life of the two systems, having easily different DNS or hosting setups, different reputation, etc... but on the negative side it means 2 registrations to pay and monitor, 2 certificates to manage, etc. 1 domain ties both fates together which can have drawbacks but simplifies maintenance/administration since all your eggs are in the same basket. Merging 2 domains into one later is simpler than the opposite generally.